# Regex to match partial string verification

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been trying unsuccessfully for the past few hours to build a Regex string that will match a partial verification of a product key.  The user will enter, for example, in a masked editbox:

```
AB3CD-EF4GH-IJK5L-MN6PQ-7RSTU
```

The regex must verify that the following match occurs:

```
..3..-...G.-..K..-M.6..-.R...
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't that the answer already?

Comment: That looks like it would work. You may need to escape the hypens, not sure about how C# handles them.

Comment: ..3..-...G.-..K..-M.6..-.R... - that's the search string?? Or that's your attempt at the regex?

Comment: @flup Nearly: he just needs backslashes.

Comment: Let me try the escape '\'. Will get back in a few minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you actually *tried* anything?

Try this:

```
static readonly Regex rxProductKey = new Regex( @"^..3..-...G.-..K..-M.6..-.R...$" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) ;

public bool IsValidProductKey( string key )
{
  bool isValid = key != null && rxProductKey.IsMatch( key ) ;
  return isValid ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The problem seems to have been the C# escape @. I can kick myself for losing so much time on such a silly oversight!

Comment: Try using an online Regex checker like rubular.com in future.  There's also a .Net one but the name escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

In your demo, you got it right! All you need is to escape the hyphens:

```
..3..\-...G.\-..K..\-M.6..\-.R...
```

Comment: You don't even have to do that: hyphens (`-`) are only special in a character class (e.g., `[A-Za-z0-9]`) where they act as a range operator, unless, they are at the left or right end of the character class (`[-zed]` or `[zed-]`), where they are treated as a literal hyphen.

Comment: @NicholasCarey Better to be safe.